# Scraping values from View Source using Requests Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So this code below is working fine but when i change the url to another site it doesn't work

```
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.autotrader.ca/a/ram/1500/hamilton/ontario/19_12052335_/?showcpo=ShowCpo&ncse=no&ursrc=pl&urp=2&urm=8&sprx=-2"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

phone_number = re.findall('"phoneNumber":"([\d-]+)"', response.text)
print(phone_number)
['905-870-7127']
```

This code below doesn't work it gives the output [] Please tell me what am i doing wrong

```
import requests
import re

urls = "https://www.kijijiautos.ca/vip/22686710/","https://www.kijijiautos.ca/vip/22686710/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    number = re.findall('"number":"([\d-]+)"', response.text)

print(number)
[]
```

Comment: regex patten is not matching

Comment: what should i change here man i tried everything. Also don't know why people are downvoting, Sorry if its a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting The HTTP 200 OK success status as a response.for that cause you are unable to get the exptected ouptput. To get the HTTP 200 OK success status, I have changed the headers from inspecting http requests.

please try this

```
import requests
import re
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.kijijiautos.ca',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'accept-language': 'en-CA',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'x-client-id': 'c89e7ff8-1d5a-4c2b-a095-c08dc08ccd3b',
    'x-client': 'ca.move.web.app',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.kijijiautos.ca/cars/hyundai/sonata/used/',
    'cookie': 'mvcid=c89e7ff8-1d5a-4c2b-a095-c08dc08ccd3b; locale=en-CA; trty=e; _gcl_au=1.1.1363596757.1633936124; _ga=GA1.2.1193080228.1633936126; _gid=GA1.2.71842091.1633936126; AAMC_kijiji_0=REGION%7C3; aam_uuid=43389576784435124231935699643302941454; _fbp=fb.1.1633936286669.1508597061; __gads=ID=bb71a6fc168c1c33:T=1633936286:S=ALNI_MZk3lgy-9xgSGLPnfrkBET60uS6fA; GCLB=COyIgrWs-PWPsQE; lux_uid=163402080128473094; cto_bundle=zxCnjF95NFglMkZrTG5EZ2dzNHFSdjJ6QSUyQkJvM1BUbk5WTkpjTms0aWdZb3RxZUR3Qk1nd1BmcSUyQjZaZVFUdFdSelpua3pKQjFhTFk0U2ViTHVZbVg5ODVBNGJkZ2NqUGg1cHZJN3V0MWlwRkQwb1htcm5nNDlqJTJGUUN3bmt6ZFkzU1J0bjMzMyUyRkt5aGVqWTJ5RVJCa2ZJQUwxcFJnJTNEJTNE; _td=7f855061-c320-4570-b2d2-73c94bd22b13; rbzid=54THgSkyCRKwhVBqy+iHmjb1RG+uE6uH1XjpsXIazO5nO45GtpIXHGYii/PbJcdG3ahjIgKaBrjh0Yx2J6YCOLHEv3QYL559oz3jQaVrssH2/1Ui9buvIpuCwBOGG2xXGWW2qvcU5807PGsdubQDUvLkxmy4sor+4EzCI1OoUHMOG2asQwsgChqwzJixVvrE21E/NJdRfDLlejb5WeGEgU4B3dOYH95yYf5h+7fxV6H/XLhqbNa8e41DM3scfyeYWeqWCWmOH2VWZ7i3oQ0OXW1SkobLy0D6G+V9J5QMxb0=; rbzsessionid=ca53a07d3404ca93b3f8bc879291dc83; _uetsid=131a47702a6211ecba407d9ff6588dde; _uetvid=131b13602a6211ecacd0b56b0815e9b2',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.kijijiautos.ca/consumer/svc/a/22686710', headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # print(response.text)
    numbers = re.findall(r'"number":"\+\d+"', response.text) # number one or more
    print(numbers[0])

else:
    print('status code is ', response.status_code)

output
# "number":"+17169905088"
```